# Event Listener not firing from JS script within HTML Import

Tags: javascript, dom-events, html-imports

I am importing `form.html` into `index.html` with the following function:

```
function importHTML() {
    let link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'import';
    link.href = 'form.html';
    link.onload = (e) => {
        console.log('Successfully loaded import: ' + e.target.href);
        importContent();
    }
    link.onerror = (e) => {
        console.log('Error loading import: ' + e.target.href);
    }
    document.head.appendChild(link);

    let importContent = () => {
        let importContent = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]').import;
        if (importContent != null) {
            let el = importContent.querySelector('#formContainer');
            let container = document.body.querySelector('main');
            container.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
        }
    }
}
```

This works to creates a new `link rel="import"` tag, appending it to the `head` of `index.html`. When the link has completed loading, the content from `form.html` is appended to the main body container.

Inside `form.html` I have a script that gets a handle to a pagination element to attach an event handler:

```
<section id="formContainer">

    <form>
        ...
    </form>

    <!-- NOTE: pagination controls -->
    <div class="pagination">
        <span id="pageBack"><i>&lt;</i></span>
        <span id="pageForward"><i>&gt;</i></span>
    </div>

    <script>

        let importDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
        let pageForward = importDoc.querySelector('#pageForward');
        let pageBack = importDoc.querySelector('#pageBack');

        // these elements are present in the console at runtime
        console.log(pageForward, pageBack);

        pageForward.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            console.log('click event heard on pageBack');
        });

        pageBack.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            console.log('click event heard on pageBack');
        });

    </script>

</section>
```

The issue I'm having is that the Event Listeners are not firing despite the console showing no errors.

I thought this might have something to do with *load order* and experimented around with this a little bit, making sure that the import loads before the script is parsed though I'm not 100% on whether or not this is working as expected.

I've found it works to move my acting script into the main document by dynamically loading it after the `importContent()` function but I'd prefer to keep the form's associated script encapsulated within the Import.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Event Listeners are attached to the wrong element. In your example, they are set on the `<span>` elements in the imported document.

But these elements are cloned and the `<span>` elements that are clicked are the cloned elements with no set Event Listeners.

To make the code work, you should query the elements form the `<body>` instead of querying the imported document.

In *form.html*:

```
<script>
let importDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument
let el = importDoc.querySelector( '#formContainer' )
let container = document.body.querySelector( 'main ' )
container.appendChild( el.cloneNode( true ) )

let pageForward = container.querySelector( '#pageForward' )
let pageBack = container.querySelector( '#pageBack')

// these elements are present in the console at runtime
console.log(pageForward, pageBack);
pageForward.addEventListener('click', e => 
    console.log( 'click event heard on pageBack' )
)

pageBack.addEventListener('click', e => 
    console.log( 'click event heard on pageBack' )
)
</script>
```

NB : the  in the imported document is executed as soon as the document is imported. No need to wait for a `onload` event and call a callback from the main document.

If you want to defer the execustion of the script, you'll need to put it in a `<template>` element.